# dpsk demodulation over a real signal

Tags: jitter, lowpass-filter, doppler

I have a real signal composed of in-phase and quadrature components. As shown in the figure, I have plotted the signal's angle for DPSK demodulation. In order to be able to demodulate, I need to first remove the effects of Doppler and jitter, etc., and then perform DPSK demodulation through phase change. But I am looking for a method that can correctly implement DPSK demodulation with MATLAB without removing the effects of Doppler and jitter, at first. One proposed method is to use a low pass filter and a multiplier, but it does not give the correct answer.. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUPsO.jpg)

I am looking for a method that can correctly implement DPSK demodulation with MATLAB without first removing the effects of Doppler and jitter. One proposed method is to use a low pass filter and a multiplier, but it does not give the correct answer.